# Why Build failed after migration to flutter 3.3.0?

Tags: flutter

lib/src/domain/application/bloc/app/app_bloc.freezed.dart:87:23:

Error: The class 'InitAppUseCase' can't be used as a mixin because it extends a class other than 'Object'.

class _$_InitApp with InitAppUseCase implements _InitApp {

Answer (score 1):

if you are using abstract class as mixin:

`abstract class InitAppUseCase extend SomeMixin{...}`

then try to use 'implements' instead of 'extends'.
if you use mixin then use 'on':

`mixin InitAppUseCase on SomClass{...}`

before flutter 3.3.0 you could fix it with:

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
  errors:
    mixin_inherits_from_not_object: ignore
```

but looks like it not work after update.
more info [Dart 2 Mixin Declarations](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.1/super-mixins/feature-specification.md#extending-a-mixin)